# Discord.py BOT that log deleted message and retrieve executor

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I am currently trying to make my own discord BOT in python. The purpose of this bot would be to store any message that is deleted and retrieve the executor of the command. If the executor cannot be found, it would assume that the deletion has been initiated by the user that written the message himself.

I successfully stored the deleted messages but I'm struggling with the second part.
I do have to verify in the **AuditLog** if a message deletion action has been triggered in the guild where the message was deleted. If this is the case, I have chosen to compare if the target of the deletion command is equal to the message author and that the deletion event has been executed less than 20 seconds ago.

The issue is that the **AuditLog** doesn't cache the event of deletion. When I compare the timestamp of the deleted message with the one of the deletion event, there's always 500+ seconds difference. I didn't find how the cache mechanics works but I also tried to add a 10s delay before checking the AuditLog but it doesn't change anything. To summary, my timestamp verification is not working at all because of this issue.

Here is my code, I want to apologize in advance because I'm still learning python so maybe it won't be that clear :

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Fonction called whenever a message is deleted by a user.
# An embed message is created to log the message that has been deleted.
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
  if message is None:
    return
  if message.guild is None:
    return
  # Verify and filter the last 3 entries of message deletion to
  # find the supposed executor of the command
  async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=3,action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
    deletionLog = None
    if (entry.target.id == message.author.id) and (((message.created_at - entry.created_at).total_seconds()) < 20):
      deletionLog = entry

  if deletionLog is None:
    embed = create_embed(discord,message,None)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    executor = deletionLog.user
    embed = create_embed(discord,message,executor)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Do you guys have any idea or workaround to make it works? Maybe I'm not doing it the right way and that would explain the issue. Also, I totally guess that there's room for improvement, so if you have any, it would be really appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance everyone !!

Comment: It seems that I was wrong.

In fact, the logs are getting generated BUT instead of generating a new entry, Discord update an older entry if the executor/target/channel are the same.

Thus, the `entry.created_at` attribute that I was using is not applicable since the creation time of the logs could be 5 minutes old. It also seems that there's no way of getting the updated date for a message deletion event since there's no **AuditLogDiff/AuditLogChanges** class defined for this event.

Comment: You are talking about a `command`, what do you mean by that? Do you just want to know who deleted the message? What is your time check for?

Comment: Hello Dominik. I wrongly used the term `command` but I was only referring to the action performed by a moderator which is the deletion of a message. I want to know who deleted the message and thus I have to check the `AuditLog`. There's no information about the message that has been deleted in the `AuditLog` so the time check (and the other check like author etc..) is there to minimize the risk of false-positive like checking the wrongs logs.

Comment: But, the thing is that Discord doesn't always generate a new log. Sometimes the logs are only getting updated and for example, instead of seeing a new log I only see that the moderator deleted 3 messages instead of 2. It seems that the API doesn't give any obvious way to perform what I want to do... Furthermore, I didn't find a way to check when the log has been updated to perform my time check from this attribute.